# Different window class for a certain window

Tags: terminal, x11, .desktop

First at all i don't know if *class* is the correct word, so my apologies.

I have this *.desktop file to open `gnuplot`

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/gabo/Pictures/icon.svg
Exec=mate-terminal -x gnuplot
Name=GNUplot
```

Which works perfectly. But, since the app is started from a terminal, the window class (and the icon) is the same for my `gnuplot` shortcut and for any other terminal.

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that i have opened both *.desktop file and a terminal emulator, and the windows buttons are grouped.

How i can differentiate between them (in the windows buttons)?

Comment: At least with `xterm`, you can override the window class with the option `-class`. I don't use mate, and `man mate-terminal` should tell you if you can do this with the mate terminal, too.